# Creating path array using IDDFS

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

My IDDFS algorithm finds the shortest path of my graph using adjacency matrix.
It shows how deep is the solution (I understand that this is amount of points connected together from starting point to end).
I would like to get these points in array.

For example:
Let's say that solution is found in depth 5, so I would like to have array with points: {0,2,3,4,6}.
Depth 3: array {1,2,3}.

Here is the algorithm in C++:
(I'm not sure if that algorithm "knows" if points which were visited are visited again while searching or not - I'm almost beginner with graphs)

```
int DLS(int node, int goal, int depth,int adj[9][9])
{
    int i,x;

    if ( depth >= 0 )
    {
        if ( node == goal )
            return node;

        for(i=0;i<nodes;i++)
        {
            if(adj[node][i] == 1)
            {
                child = i;
                x = DLS(child, goal, depth-1,adj);

                if(x == goal)
                    return goal;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int IDDFS(int root,int goal,int adj[9][9])
{
    depth = 0;
    solution = 0;
    while(solution <= 0 && depth < nodes)
    {
        solution = DLS(root, goal, depth,adj);
        depth++;
    }
    if(depth  == nodes)
        return inf;

    return depth-1;
}

int main()
{
    int i,u,v,source,goal;

int adj[9][9] = {{0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
       {1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0},
       {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
       {1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},
       {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
       {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1},
       {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0},
       {0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
       {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0}
    };

    nodes=9;
    edges=12;

    source=0;
    goal=8;

    depth = IDDFS(source,goal,adj);

    if(depth == inf)printf("No solution Exist\n");
    else printf("Solution Found in depth limit ( %d ).\n",depth);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

The reason why I'm using IDDFS instead of other path-finding algorithm is that I want to change depth to specified number to search for paths of exact length (but I'm not sure if that will work).

---

If someone would suggest other algorithm for finding path of specified length using adjacency matrix, please let me know about it.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of getting the actual path retrieved from a pathfinding algorithm is to use a `map:V->V` such that the key is a vertex, and the value is the vertex used to discover the key (The source will not be a key, or be a key with `null` value, since it was not discovered from any vertex).

The pathfinding algorithm will modify this map while it runs, and when it is done - you can get your path by reading from the table iteratively - starting from the target - all the way up to the source - and you get your path in reversed order.

In [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search): you insert the `(key,value)` pair each time you discover a new vertex (which is `key`). Note that if `key` is already a key in the map - you should skip this branch.

Once you finish exploring a certain path, and "close" a vertex, you need take it out of the list, However - sometimes you can optimize the algorithm and skip this part (it will make the branch factor smaller).

Since IDDFS is actually doing DFS iteratively, you can just follow the same logic, and each time you make a new DFS iteration - for higher depth, you can just clear the old map, and start a new one from scratch.

Other pathfinding algorithms are are [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) and [dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Note that the last 2 also fit for weighted graphs. All of these can be terminated when you reach a certain depth, same as DFS is terminated when you reach a certain depth in IDDFS.

Comment: But I want to have not the shortest path, but longer. I'll give to the algorithm specified length of the path and it should find such one for me. I don't know how to use these algorithms to solve this problem.